# Seeking a kids' show involving a frog prince

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm trying to remember a show from the 1980s that involved a frog prince plot, connected to goings-on at an ordinary American high school.  It may have been one hour long or two, perhaps in two parts.  The problem is that while I recall the high school drama part of the story reasonably well, I don't remember what the fantasy aspects had to do with anything.

The main character (a white male teenager) is campaigning to be the spring dance king.  His African-American best friend is his campaign manager, and the other serious candidate is jock.  The main character has a blonde girlfriend, but his relationship with her is getting strained, and she is sort of falling for the jock (who turns out to have a great deal of depth, like knowing some Latin).  At the same time, the main character is falling for a younger, nerdy, dark-haired student, who is not interested in the dance at all; she spends her free time down at the swamp studying the amphibians.

Somehow, the main character gets involved with a frog (who probably can talk, but maybe only him).  I think he needs to get a kiss to transform the frog (back?) into a human, but I don't remember much about that plot, except that once the frog forces the main character to stay up all night.  The next morning, his campaign manager gives him eyedrops, so he doesn't have obvious red eyes at the upcoming assembly.

The frog probably plays some role in the main character winning the election, but I don't remember it.  But win he does, which is a surprise to him.  He dances with his girlfriend at the formal dance.  Then they agree to break up, and he leaves the event.  He heads down to the swamp to meet the other girl, and they end up dancing thigh-deep in water, she wearing hip waders and he still in his tuxedo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to this TV movie from 1987 with the talking frog: http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0162334/